# Can someone help me to combine multiple command into one Line

Tags: command-line

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum

sudo apt update

sudo apt install ethereum
mkdir ethminer

wget -O ethminer/ethminer.tar.gz https://github.com/ethereum-mining/ethminer/releases/download/v0.18.0/ethminer-0.18.0-cuda-9-linux-x86_64.tar.gz

tar xzf ethminer/ethminer.tar.gz -C ethminer/

ethminer/bin/ethminer --help

cd ethminer 

./bin/ethminer -U -P stratum1+tcp://secret@eth.2miners.com:2020
```

Comment: use spaces or not?

Comment: ok sir thanks for help, i will try

Comment: I'd have used ";"  ("&" throws the command in the background; not exactly what likely want), but there are many options, eg. "&&" lets the subsequent command run only if the first succeeded etc.   (using '&&' in the context likely makes sense given you don't want to execute following if failures occur with prior..)

Comment: Why do you need just one line?

Comment: because I want it to be fast, no need to be tired of copying and pasting one by one

Answer (score 1):

Read [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Lists.html), and you can get ideas on how to accomplish the task:

> Commands separated by a ‘;’ are executed sequentially; the shell waits
> for each command to terminate in turn. The return status is the exit
> status of the last command executed.
>
> AND and OR lists are sequences of one or more pipelines separated by
> the control operators ‘&&’ and ‘||’, respectively. AND and OR lists
> are executed with left associativity.
>
> An AND list has the form
>
> ```
> command1 && command2
> ```
>
> `command2` is executed if, and only if, `command1` returns an exit status
> of zero (success).
>
> An OR list has the form
>
> ```
> command1 || command2
> ```
>
> `command2` is executed if, and only if, `command1` returns a non-zero exit
> status.
>
> The return status of AND and OR lists is the exit status of the last
> command executed in the list.